# Route two audio inputs into one

Tags: linux, audio, pulse-audio

I need to use two inputs (microphone and virtual monitor) and create one input from it, in order to use one single input in discord. Currently using Arch Linux and pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0):

Superuser is not a site for software recommendations, but I *can* state that there is software that could help, such as audio mixer applications, e.g., [JACK](https://jackaudio.org/), [KXStudio](https://kx.studio/) and [Mixx](https://mixxx.org/).

My own experience with JACK is that it is powerful, but setup required some experimentation.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out JACK... I'm not even looking for software recommendations, I just have literally no clue where to start. Everything I see online isn't helpful.

Comment: @silvanathecat, agreed! There is a discussion at https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=22770 . Regrettably, I have *not* used JACK enough (nor ALSA) to be of help -- you might create another question here, e.g., "How do I configure a new JACK installation to mix two channels?"